# Creating a new installer for an old VB6 program

Tags: vb6, installation

Recently my boss told me that he wants a new installer for his program he created in Visual Basic 6 back in 2001, moreover he said "he want's it to be like one of those Adobe installers".

so to make a long story short, for the past few days I've been using everything i could find but none of the solutions I've found(mostly software) yielded any results

To clarify, he specifically told me to do it without the source code of the program 
all i have to work with is the programs actual installer (which is not even .msi) the .CAB file of the program and a file folder where he keeps some support files for the actual installation method.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? "How do I write a custom installer?" That's rather broad.

Comment: i guess that could be a solution, but i'm not exactly well versed in VB6. Also what i was trying to ask is How doable is it to make a brand new installer for a 10Yo program and if it is doable What do i need in order to do it , not how to do it

Comment: Strikes me that you should be asking your boss for clarification/ guidance on this one

Comment: Setup of 10Yo programs is pretty much the same or easier than brand new apps -- copy files, register dlls, create shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Your old setup is PDW based and should have a Setup.lst file which lists all the files, where and how to install them.
This can easily [converted to an Inno Setup script](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb) that provides a much nice and more up to date "installation experiance" than the PDW can natively.

Comment: just to clarify this part what he meant was "make it as brain dead as possible" i.e have the user the least involved in the installation process aside from clicking a few yes and next's

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the Inno KB article on installing VB applications which contains a section on how to convert the setup.lst file.

Comment: Mark me down as *not a fan of Inno*.  It is probably great in competant hands, but I have had Inno-made setups trash too many other applications.  Often when uninstalled the Inno uninstaller deletes components other programs are using.  Look for a safer alternative.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Noted but I'm sure it's just as easy in Wise, Nullsoft (maybe not MSI) or rather just bad application code. Yes, developer tools, do require proper developer knowledge and experiance IMO.

Comment: Most other tools tend to provide more of a safety net for casual users though.  Every time I've had to help a customer "repair" one of my applications because a shared library "went away" I have tracked it to an Inno installer.  There are just too many half-baked sample "scripts" out there in the wild that get used as examples.  Inno is like a chainsaw with no safety features on it.

Comment: @user1546352 If this answer helped solve your problem, can you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green tick to the left of the post.
If it didn't, can you provide more information on what you're trying to do and how the suggestion didn't work.